# How to pre-populate data to table?

Tags: java, android, objectbox

Recently I have found the [article about Room db](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1) and there was first tip for pre-populating the data to database.

Is there currently some elegant way to pre-populate the data when the database is created?

I am using Dagger2, so the actual creation of the database is done quite easy.

```
@Module
class DatabaseModule{

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideObjectBox(context: Context): BoxStore =
        MyObjectBox.builder()
                .androidContext(context)
                .build()

}
```

And the way I am doing it now with the SharedPreferences. So I am just checking if it is the first set up of the database and than populating the database.

Answer (score 0):

Also i guess when the question was created it was not possible there is a function added to the builder so you can simply call:

```
 MyObjectBox.builder()
            .initialDbFile(file)
            .androidContext(context)
            .build()
```

This will use the given file must contain all data in mdb format. I am using this feature for backuping user data so i dont have to create the file on my own.
As far as i know there is no easy posibility to create this file instead of creating objects and putting them in the boxStore.
I am copying the file with already existing data like this (not the pretty way though)

```kotlin
     val dbFile = File(File(File(activity.getFilesDir(), "objectbox"),  BoxStoreBuilder.DEFAULT_NAME), "data.mdb")
```

---

Just found the main contributer answered the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51765399/8524651